# Getting Java copied array to take a different list from original and sort

Tags: java, arrays

Assume that my RandomArray class and my insertion sort code works, because they both do. The problem I seem to be having is that in this code, the same list keeps being sorted. I'm trying to create a copy of the original array (myNums) and copy the contents to the array called copy, and then do the sort. however as i said it seems to be sorting the same array constantly.

This is my code. Most of the comments can be ignored.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i;
    // Gen Array
    RandomArray mynose = new RandomArray(10);
    int[] myNums = mynose.init();
    /* FileInputArray myInputMaker = new FileInputArray();
    int[] myNums = myInputMaker.getNumbers(args[0]); */
    // For repeats = 1...5
    int[] copy = new int[10];
    long execution_time = 0;
    for (int o = 1; o < 100; o += 1) {
        System.arraycopy(myNums, 0, copy, 0, 10);
        long start_time = System.nanoTime ();
        insertion_srt(copy, copy.length);
        execution_time += System.nanoTime () - start_time;
        System.out.println(o + "," + (int)execution_time/100.0);
        /* FileOutput toFile = new FileOutput();
        myNums = toFile.writeToFile(copy); */
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to copy a different array, you need a different array to copy from.

Comment: can you expand on that?

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of mynose inside the for loop and it will be randomized. Right now, it's initialized once, then you're calling sort on the same thing. If you put it inside the loop, it will be randomly shuffled every time.

Comment: RandomArray mynose = new RandomArray(10);
  int[] myNums = mynose.init();               both of these inside the for loop at the start?

Comment: No; those are outside the for loop.

Comment: so if im not to move them into the for loop, then what do you mean?

Comment: That's exactly what you should do

Comment: The resulting times are still linear, meaning that the code is still sorting the same list, or, the code is sorting the first list that was already sorted

Comment: basically i cant get a quadratic showing of the times. worst case for insertion sort. which is O(n^2). @JamesGrammatikos

Answer (score 0):

You only created an array, everytime you copy, you copy the original array, so it will sort the "same" array.

Assuming that your init method returns a new array with random numbers you should move the line:

```
int[] myNums = mynose.init();
```

to be the first line of your for method, so for each iteration you will have a new array with new numbers (again, assuming that init correctly chooses the random numbers).

Comment: so what should i do instead?

Comment: public class RandomArray {
  
  //public int[] randomInt;
  public int[] randomNumber;
  int max = 999;
  
  public RandomArray(int N) {
    randomNumber = new int[N];
  }
  Random r = new Random();
  
  public int[] init () {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumber.length; i++) {
      randomNumber[i] = r.nextInt(max);
   //return randomNumber[];
  }
 return randomNumber;
  
  }
  
  //public double[] sortRandom() {
   //return randomNumber.sort();
  }

Comment: i know thats hard to read. but does that look correct for what you're saying? what you're saying is what i want.